# How to append to a string in powershell passed into a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, string-concatenation

I have a method that takes in a string as a parameter. This string is concatenated with values. At the end of processing I require the complete concatenated string

```
function MyFunction()
{
    Param ($output)

    $msg = "x " #say this x was different per call
    $output += $msg
}

$output = "start "
MyFunction -output $output
MyFunction -output $output
MyFunction -output $output

Write-Host $output
```

**Output**

```
"start "
```

**Expected**

```
"start 1 2 3 "
```

I've looked up using [ref] but this applies to value types and not reference types.

**Update**

How do you pass different named variables to functions, i.e.

```
$output1 = "start1 "
$output2 = "start2 "

MyFunction -output $output1
MyFunction -output $output2

WriteHost($output1)
WriteHost($output2)
```

Expecting result

start1.... appended from within MyFunction
start2.... appended from within MyFunction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inside your function, you are not in the same scope than the rest of the script.
So you have to specify the script scope when you update $output by using $script:output :

```
$output= "start "
function MyFunction()
{
    Param ($output)

    $msg = "x " #say this x was different per call
    $script:output+=$msg


}


MyFunction -output $output
MyFunction -output $output
MyFunction -output $output

Write-Host $output
```

Comment: Updated my question to include different named variables, any ideas?

Comment: what result do you expect ?

Comment: Updated again, the variable I pass through to the function I want appending to and then display the result afterwards. To me it seems the variable name declared has to be the same variable name in the function?

Comment: add `$script:output` at the end of your function that should do what you want

Comment: but the variables are named $output1 and $output2. could you explain more?

Comment: still dont understand what you want. you want to update the value of $output1 & $output2 not just display them ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22567/discussion-between-kayasax-and-david-liddle)